# sortby using Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to sort certain records using underscore `_.sortby()` function . My requirement is to give higher priority for names starting with _ . For eg . if my code is

```
var patients = [
    [{name: 'John', roomNumber: 1, bedNumber: 1}],
    [{name: 'Lisa', roomNumber: 1, bedNumber: 2}],
    [{name: '_A', roomNumber: 2, bedNumber: 1}],
    [{name: 'Omar', roomNumber: 3, bedNumber: 1}]
];
var sortedArray = _.sortBy(patients, function(patient) {
    return patient[0].name;
});
```

I would want to have the record _A, roomNumber: 2, bedNumber: 1 to be on the top . In a sense I want the sort to ignore the strings starting with _

Comment: your question is unclear, once you say give priority to `_` then you say ignore `_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```js
var patients = [
    [{name: '_John', roomNumber: 1, bedNumber: 1}],
    [{name: 'Lisa', roomNumber: 1, bedNumber: 2}],
    [{name: '_A', roomNumber: 2, bedNumber: 1}],
    [{name: 'Amar', roomNumber: 3, bedNumber: 1}]
];

var sortedByChar = _.sortBy(patients, function(patient) {
  
  return (patient[0].name.indexOf('_') != 0) ? patient[0].name[0] : patient[0].name[1];
  
});

var finalArray = _.sortBy(sortedByChar, function(patient) {
  return (patient[0].name.indexOf('_') != 0); 
});

alert(JSON.stringify(finalArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

You can play around with the fiddle by adding underscores to other names and see how it sorts.

Comment: If you add A in the record set I am getting A as the last record . Ideally I would require A after _A

Comment: Sorry for the confusion . Actually can we modify the logic to check if the name starts with a _

Comment: we are checking for that in the logic right?? the indexOf('_')

Answer (score 2):

[`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) sorts `_` to top (at any case).

```js
var patients = [[{ name: 'John', roomNumber: 1, bedNumber: 1 }], [{ name: 'Lisa', roomNumber: 1, bedNumber: 2 }], [{ name: 'a', roomNumber: 2, bedNumber: 1 }], [{ name: 'A', roomNumber: 2, bedNumber: 1 }], [{ name: '_A', roomNumber: 2, bedNumber: 1 }], [{ name: 'Omar', roomNumber: 3, bedNumber: 1 }], [{ name: '_Omar', roomNumber: 3, bedNumber: 1 }]],
sortedArray = patients.sort( function (a,b) {
    return a[0].name.localeCompare(b[0].name);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sortedArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: `sortby using Underscore` is the question

Comment: @Reddy yes, you are right. should i delete my answer?

Comment: :) naaaa I wanted to see your logic in the underscore sortby stuff.. nothing else mate.. no offense

Comment: @Reddy, never mind. i don't know underscore. that's all.

Comment: While this isn't underscorejs, I think this is really better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var sortedArray = _.sortBy(patients, function(patient) {
    return patient[0].name.replace('_', '0');
});
```

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s7r2kxhq/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by converting the string to lowercase:

```js
var patients = [ [{name: 'John', roomNumber: 1, bedNumber: 1}], [{name: 'Lisa', roomNumber: 1, bedNumber: 2}], [{name: '_A', roomNumber: 2, bedNumber: 1}], [{name: 'Omar', roomNumber: 3, bedNumber: 1}] ];

var sortedArray = _.sortBy(patients, function(patient) {
    return patient[0].name.toLowerCase();
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(sortedArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the possibilities of doing this is updating the iteratee in the _.sortBy to something like following

```
function(value){
    if(value[name].substr(1) != '_') {
        return "z" + value[name];   
    } 
    return value[name];
}
```

This function will append to the beginning a character which code value is higher than _, meaning that everything else will be ordered after the values with _

Answer (score -2):

Use `Array.prototype.sort` and test if the name has an "_"

```
var sortedArray = patients.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (/^_/.test(a[0].name)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return a[0].name < b[0].name ? -1 : 1;
});
```

And your js object is a little weird, why do you have an array around your object ?

Comment: Please use workplace-appropriate language on Stack Overflow, not language which may be offensive to some groups of people. Please see: [Are expletives (cursing, swear words, vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites) Keep in mind that using offensive language tends to result in people reacting poorly to your posts (i.e. they may downvote). In addition, do you really want a future employer to see you using such language in a situation which is intended to be professional?

Comment: I've edited the bad word out of your answer for now.