# How to sort an object array by multiple keys in javascript using _.sortBy() method of Javascript Underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

I am sorting an object array by multiple keys using the **_.sortBy()** method of **Javascript Underscore.js**. I used the first name and last name inside the names object for sorting.

My Code:

```
var names = [
  { fname: 'Chloe', lname: 'Bennet' },
  { fname: 'Adam', lname: 'Levine' },
  { fname: 'Chris', lname: 'Hemsworth' },
  { fname: 'Justin', lname: 'Bieber' },
  { fname: 'Chloe', lname: 'Moretz' },
  { fname: 'Taylor', lname: 'Swift' }
];

console.log(_.sortBy(someData, 'fname' + ' ' + 'lname')
```

Expected result:

```
{ fname: 'Adam', lname: 'Levine' },
{ fname: 'Chloe', lname: 'Bennet' },
{ fname: 'Chloe', lname: 'Moretz' },
{ fname: 'Chris', lname: 'Hemsworth' },
{ fname: 'Justin', lname: 'Bieber' },
{ fname: 'Taylor', lname: 'Swift' }
```

But it is not sorting the array.

Comment: so, what's the right result? include it in your question.

Comment: Did you consider reading the doc? https://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

Comment: The right answer is in the Expected result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sortby using Underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057313/sortby-using-underscore)

Comment: oh, sorry. didn't notice. i mean your current result.

Comment: It's not sorting.

Comment: `_.sortBy` takes either name of the property(in string) or a function as its second parameter. consider use a function in your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide function for more complex comparisons:

```js
var names = [
  { fname: 'Chloe', lname: 'Bennet' },
  { fname: 'Adam', lname: 'Levine' },
  { fname: 'Chris', lname: 'Hemsworth' },
  { fname: 'Justin', lname: 'Bieber' },
  { fname: 'Chloe', lname: 'Moretz' },
  { fname: 'Taylor', lname: 'Swift' }
];

console.log(_.sortBy(names, ({ fname, lname }) => fname + ' ' + lname))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great thanks! It's actually working and it's more lesser code than the one I thought.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

```
var names = [
  { fname: 'Chloe', lname: 'Bennet' },
  { fname: 'Adam', lname: 'Levine' },
  { fname: 'Chris', lname: 'Hemsworth' },
  { fname: 'Justin', lname: 'Bieber' },
  { fname: 'Chloe', lname: 'Moretz' },
  { fname: 'Taylor', lname: 'Swift' }
];
console.log(_.sortBy(names, ['fname', 'lname']));
```

Regards,
Vincent

Comment: My bad, I thought you were talking about the lodash library, not underscore.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with my answer. Thanks to everyone for giving me idea.

```js
var names = [
  { fname: 'Chloe', lname: 'Bennet' },
  { fname: 'Adam', lname: 'Levine' },
  { fname: 'Chris', lname: 'Hemsworth' },
  { fname: 'Justin', lname: 'Bieber' },
  { fname: 'Chloe', lname: 'Moretz' },
  { fname: 'Taylor', lname: 'Swift' }
];

console.log(
    _.sortBy(names , 
       function(value) {
         return value.fname + ' ' + value.lname;
       }
    )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```